# array-based implementations of list(cursor implementation)

Tags: java, arrays, stack

I want to use a cursor to build a stack, but I really does not understand the whole cursor implementation

```
public class cursor {

    private int header;
    static cursorNode[ ] cursor;

    private static final int SPACE_SIZE = 100;

    static
    {
        cursor = new cursorNode[ SPACE_SIZE ];
        for( int i = 0; i < SPACE_SIZE; i++ )
            cursor[ i ] = new cursorNode( null, i + 1 );
        cursor[ SPACE_SIZE - 1 ].next = 0;
    } 
    public static int alloc( )
    {
        int p = cursor[ 0 ].next;
        if( p == 0 )
            return 0;
        cursor[ 0 ].next = cursor[ p ].next;
        cursor[ p ].next=0;
        return p;
    }

    public static void free( int p )
    {

        cursor[ p ].next = cursor[ 0 ].next;
        cursor[ 0 ].next = p;
    }
    public cursor( )
    {
        header = alloc( );
        cursor[ header ].next = 0;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty( )
    {
        return cursor[ header ].next == 0;
    }
    public void addFirst(int l, Object x){
        int temp=alloc();
        cursor[temp].element=x;
        cursor[temp].next=cursor[l].next;
        cursor[l].next=temp;
    }
    public boolean removeFirst(int l){
        if(cursor[l].next==0)
            return false;
        int p =cursor[l].next;
        cursor[l].next=cursor[p].next;
        free(p);
        return true;
    }
    public void print(int l){
        int p=cursor[l].next;
        while(p!=0){
            System.out.print(cursor[p].element);
            p=cursor[p].next;
        }
    }


}.

public class cursorNode {
    Object   element;
    int      next;

      public cursorNode(Object x ){
           this( x, 0 );
       }

      public cursorNode(Object x, int n )
       {
           element = x;
           next    = n;
       }


   }
```

Can you explain what is cursor implementation and how to use it to build a stack.
I understand that push() will use addFirst(), and pop() uses removeFirst(), but how to top() will work.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking. Are you looking for an explanation of the code you posted or suggestions on how to implement a `top` method?

Comment: I am looking for both. but if you can provide a stack that use this code for now would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, an explanation of what the code you posted does. It is essentially a way of managing several collections of values that are stored in a fixed sized pool. It is designed so that as items are removed from a collection they are returned to a free list to be reused. It is poorly written in many ways but given you haven't asked for review comments I'll skip them.

Secondly, how can you use this code to implement a stack? Answer: you can't. There are no public methods to retrieve values (required for a peek operation) and the `removeFirst` method returns a `boolean` rather than the value being removed. You will need to change this code in order to use it to implement a stack.

Comment: how to implement getFirst().

Comment: You will need to give me better information on where you need help. If you are asking me to write the code then my answer is that I wouldn't use the cursor class to implement a stack.